# Expose function reference to be accessed from outside

Tags: javascript, scope

I have this code, where I add my button click listeners to call my `startTempMonit` function

```
$(function () {
    const inter;
    $("#buttonStartTemp").click(function () {
        inter = startTempMonit(onFetchCallback.store);
    });

    $("#buttonStopTemp").click(function () {
        clearInterval(inter); //inter is undefined
    });
});

function startTempMonit(callback) {
    var time = 0;
    const Interval= setInterval(function () {
        ...
    }, 500);
    return Interval;
}
```

I would like o to know how to expose the returned `const Interval` in the `startTempMonit` so as to be able to clear it when I click the other button (`#buttonStopTemp`).

I also tried defining `const inter;` in the outest scope, which I would not like, but its does not work either.

Comment: Well don't use `const inter;` but `let inter` or `var inter`. You should be getting a clear error message when trying to assign the constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initialize a constant. Instead, declare `inter` with `var`:

```js
$(function () {
    var inter;
    $("#buttonStartTemp").click(function () {
        inter = startTempMonit(()=>console.log(1));
    });

    $("#buttonStopTemp").click(function () {
        clearInterval(inter);
    });
});

function startTempMonit(callback) {
    var time = 0;
    const Interval= setInterval(callback, 500);
    return Interval;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="buttonStartTemp">Start</button>
<button id="buttonStopTemp">Stop</button>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I needed to restart my explorer with ctrl + shift + R because it was not getting the code changes I was making, lol. With `let` it works. No need of `var`